# jQuery show and active a selected item ul after reload?

Tags: jquery, menu, html-lists

I have a jQuery animated menu, but when i click on an item (menu point) the site reload an show the content and the first view of the menu, but no the selected menu item.

How can i active the item and open the selected ul after reload?

```
$('a.forward').next().hide();

/* Forward Button */
$('a.forward').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).next().clone(true, true).appendTo(".subnav").css({
        position: "absolute", 
        left:"190px", 
        top:"0", 
        display:"block"}).animate({
            left:"0"
    }, 300);

    $(this).closest("ul").animate({
        left:"-190px",
    }, 300);

    return false;
});

/* Back Button */
$('a.back').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest("ul").prev().animate({
        left:"0",
    }, 300);

    $(this).closest("ul").animate({
        left:"200px",
    }, 300, "linear",function(){$(this).remove()});
    return false;
});

var targetAnchor;
$.each ($('ul.lsb-menu a'), function() {
    if( this.href == window.location ) {
        targetAnchor = this;
        return false;
    }
});

var parent = $(targetAnchor).closest('li');

while(true) {
    parent.addClass('active');

    if( $(parent).parents('ul.lsb-menu').length <= 0 ) break;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mh35b/5/

Comment: This can be done with css, in the content pages, add a class to the body and in the css, show the item that's related to the page content

Comment: When i click on Menu A >> 1 >> 1.1 for example the site load the content from 1.1 but this is a new load of the site.

I see than again the first Menu A, B, C and D not the 1.1. that i click. I have add the right class "active" but i see the general first menu not the activited.

Comment: Are you going to a different page or is this reload happening on the same page?

Comment: The page is the same, but the href ist "main.php?page=1", main.php?page=2, main.php?page=3 and and and.... i see the content of the link but the menu view is the first (menu a, b, c and d) not the activited item.